# Solve equation of second degree - congruence

Tags: congruences

I have following equation:
$$n^2 - n + 2\equiv 0\pmod{49}$$

So I get:
$$n^2 - n + 2\equiv 0\pmod{7}$$
The only number is:
$$n\equiv 4 \pmod7$$

Thus, I used Hensel's Lemma. And according to (3) point (http://math453spring2009.wikidot.com/hensel-s-lemma)
We see that there is no sulution when we have $7^2$.

What about my solution ? Is it correct ? Maybe somebody has other idea?

Comment: Let $P(x)=x^2-x+2$. Then $P'(4)$ is divisible by $7$ and $P(4)$ is not divisible by $7^2$, so the solution $x\equiv 4\pmod{7}$ does not lift.  That should be stated explicitly.

Comment: You should explicitly mention the conditions that you checked to apply case $(3)$ of the linked version of Hensel's Lemma.

Comment: But my solution is $generally$ ok ?

Answer (score 4):

A solution without Hansel's Lemma: suppose there is an integer $n$ such that $n^2-n+2$ is divisible by $49$. Then
$$
n^2-n+2=n^2-8n+16+7n-14=(n-4)^2+7n-14
$$
is divisible by $7$ so $(n-4)^2$ is divisible by $7$, which further implies $n-4$ is divisible by $7$. So you actually have $(n-4)^2$ is divisible by $49$. Now, write $n=7m+4$. Observe that
$$
7n-14=7(7m+4)-14=49m+14,
$$
which isn't divisible by $49$. Contradiction.

Comment: And no Gretel either?

Comment: Bad Willie, no gingerbread for you!

Comment: You did type Hansel, though, ought to be Hensel. Don't think gingerbread is my sort of thing. We did get these seasonal PfefferNusse when I was a kid, liked those.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfeffern%C3%BCsse Not sure whether they were imported or baked here.

Comment: I was suggesting that you edit your first line.

Comment: I understood you, but editing would ruin your joke.

Comment: Ahhh, good thinking.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, if
$$ x^2 - x y + 2 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {49},   $$ then both $x,y \equiv 0 \pmod 7.$

BECAUSE $2$ is invertible $\bmod 7,$ and
$$  4 x^2 - 4 x y + 8 y^2 = (2x-y)^2 + 7 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {49},  $$
so first $$ (2x-y) \equiv 0 \pmod 7. $$
However, this gives
$$ (2x-y)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {49}, $$
with
$$ 7 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {49},  $$
$$  y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7,$$
$$ y \equiv 0 \pmod 7.  $$
Finally
$$  2x \equiv 0 \pmod 7  $$ and
$$ x \equiv 0 \pmod 7  $$

So, there is no solution with my letter $y=1,$ meaning the original question has no integer solutions.